# How could I get mouse click coordinates using Swift on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, coordinates, line, draw

I try to find out about getting mouse click coordinates to draw a line. I would like to make two clicks (first and second dots) and a line'll be create.

I analysed a lot of codes, but they are huge (for example, I'm fond of this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496766/9058168).

I hope drawing line in Swift isn't difficult. Could I type another variable which has mouse click coordinates instead of numeral coordinates (look at code below)? If your answer is true, how to code it? Help me, please, to make it simplier.

```
import Cocoa

class DrawLine: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the mouse down event and set start location and end location using it to draw the path.

```
import Cocoa

class DrawLine: NSView {
    var startPoint:NSPoint?
    var endPoint:NSPoint?
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent){
        if startPoint == nil || self.endPoint != nil{
           self.startPoint = event.locationInWindow
        } else {
          self.endPoint = event.locationInWindow
          self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if let theStart = startPoint, let theEnd = endPoint{
           NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: theStart, to: theEnd)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you mean 'user has no idea what is happening'? What indication does the user need?

Comment: That's a matter of user experience. Not related to the solution or the question.

Comment: Your code is running, but I cannot draw a line. I make two clicks, and the line isn't be appeared. Maybe I do something wrong..

Comment: @DevidOtladka Was it appearing when you drew by explicitly providing the start and end points? If not you should set your view's frame and the stroke color properly.

Comment: What should I set? I draw on ImageView. The line with coordinates is appeared. But when I try to use this code, the result is no. I’ve tried to make start and end point exactly.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in `mouseDown` and see if its even getting called?

Comment: @LeoDabus No `draw` gets called when the view is interacted with. Verified it in the playground. It produced the same results with and without setting needs display.

Comment: @DevidOtladka Edited my answer to include setting `self.needsDisplay` to `true`. It should work now. Please try.

Comment: Also don't draw on an `NSImageView` that's not what it's for — it's for drawing pre-made images like GIF and TIFF and JPG. Just draw in the `draw()` function as shown.